# Why JSON parse return undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

This is the string goes in:

```
"{"eventId":"program-1","eventTimesSelected":{"243759548768171":"2021-11-30T23:00:00Z"}}"
```

And it fails basically, why?

```
const startPaymentIn2 = localStorage.getItem("startPaymentIn");
let startPaymentIn3 = JSON.parse(startPaymentIn2);
```

Maybe only debugger plan fun with me?

[image]

Comment: just asking out of curiosity, why doesn't the string have escaped `"` in them? could this be the reason?

Comment: Does the in-string contain the outer quotation marks? If so this could be why.

Comment: Data comes from localStorage and was used `JSON.stringify` at export

Comment: It works fine, if your original string is in single quotes: https://jsfiddle.net/9xu46fm8/

Comment: Even when using the original object, _stringify-ing_ it, and parsing it, it seams to be working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/9xu46fm8/1/. Maybe your error is not in the string itself. Could you post a larger portion of the relevent code, so we can check if anything is altering the string ?

Comment: You are right @Nicolas, I stepped forward debugger, and debugger treated the output as it is not undefined, though you can see in screen shot `undefined` is written.

Answer (score 0):

It's the quotations, try this instead

Javascript gets confused the three first characters, "{" is a solitary string.

You can read more about strings [here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20there%20are%20three,used%20throughout%20the%20same%20script.)

```js
let JSONString = `{"eventId":"program-1","eventTimesSelected":{"243759548768171":"2021-11-30T23:00:00Z"}}`

let jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSONString)

console.log(jsonObject)
```